# Carabiner not working--Codeigniter library

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having trouble getting Carabiner to work...

There aren't any errors--my files just aren't working.

I haven't changed the config.

In my function I have:

```
    $this->load->library('carabiner');
    $this->carabiner->display();
```

This should output all the css and js in my asstes folder, right?

I've tried moving the assets folder around too.  Right now it's in /application/assets

Am I getting something wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you also need to grab the js and css using the carabiner object:

```
// add a js file
$this->carabiner->js('scripts.js');

// add a css file
$this->carabiner->css('reset.css');

// add a css file with a mediatype
$this->carabiner->css('admin/print.css','print');
```

see http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Carabiner/

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('carabiner');
$this->carabiner->css('file1.css');// load as many css file as you want.
$this->carabiner->css('file2.css');// load as many css file as you want.
$this->carabiner->js('file1.js');// load as many js file as you want.
$this->carabiner->js('file2.js');// load as many cjs file as you want.
$this->carabiner->display(); // output html which loads cached files
```

**Please refer this site where it gives step by step guide to implement it.**
[Carabiner integration with codeigniter](http://www.webdevelopersdiary.com/blog/minifying-combining-a%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bnd-caching-css-and-j%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs-with-code-ingiter)

Comment: This question is really old and already answered. Does your answer add something helpful?